# Accordion default closed jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to make an accordion closed by default but not sure where I'm going wrong, can anyone suggest something?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // create accordion variables
        var accordion = $(this);
        var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');
        var accordionToggleIcon = $(this).children('.toggle-icon');
        // toggle accordion link open class
        accordion.toggleClass("open");
        // toggle accordion content
        accordionContent.slideToggle(250);

        // change plus/minus icon
        if (accordion.hasClass("open")) {
            accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i>");
        } else {
            accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i>");
        }
    });
});

$('.accordion-toggle').accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Comment: can you please provide an example ? (e.g. jsFiddle; with your html-code)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jonSnow70/yg7e3c0b/

Sorry, here it is.

Comment: Fiddle does not work